# how to print 'user imported' module name and version in python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to print imported module name & version in colab
This is my code

```
import numpy as np
....and so on....

ref_dict = {'pd': 'pandas', 'np': 'numpy', 'sns': 'seaborn', 'plt': 'matplotlib'}
as_name =[x for x in set(sys.modules) & set(globals())]
as_ref = [ref_dict[x] for x in dir() if x in ref_dict.keys()]
module_list= as_name + as_ref
a, na=[], []

print('--module name & versions imported by user--\n')
for name in module_list:
    try: a.append('{}: {}'.format(name, sys.modules[name].__version__))
    except: na.append('{}: {}'.format(name, 'Not available'))

print(*a,'\n-----\n', *na, sep='\n')
```

this is the result

```
--module name & versions imported by user--

torch: 1.8.0+cu101
re: 2.2.1
tqdm: 4.41.1
sklearn: 0.22.2.post1
numpy: 1.19.5
pandas: 1.1.5
matplotlib: 3.2.2
seaborn: 0.11.1

-----

os: Not available
sys: Not available
__main__: Not available
```

As seen above, ref_dict specifies module imported by alias, which I don't want to do so.
is there any better way to see imported module versions and names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you a list of all the imported modules

```
{value.__name__ for value in globals().values() if inspect.ismodule(value)}
```

So it's similar to what you are using, but instead of using the aliased name in global(), it gets the actual name of the module.

Notice that it requires you to import inspect, so `inspect` and `builtins` are part of the list as well

```
In [1]: import inspect

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: {value.__name__ for value in globals().values() if inspect.ismodule(value)}
Out[3]: {'builtins', 'inspect', 'pandas'}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. anyway, importing like 'from tqdm.notebook import tqdm' does not appears in this code.

Comment: not very pythonic, but
    module_list=set([x for x in set(sys.modules) & set(globals())] + [value.__name__ for value in globals().values() if inspect.ismodule(value)])
this one was printing modules including tqdm